# Solving an RLC circuit with two voltage sources using Laplace transforms

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, laplace-transform, voltage-source

What is the Laplace transform for an RLC circuit with two voltage sources? I tried to find I(s), but the calculation gets complicated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't solve homework problems, but if you attempt a solution and ask specific questions about where you're stuck, we will provide hints.

Comment: @JohnD i'm trying to find vc at t>0  i found vc at t<0 which is 50v and then i changed the switch position then i converted the 5mh inductor and the capacitor to their equivalent Laplace domain impedance forms and i tried to calculate Vc but i couldn't

Comment: Why couldn't you? Show your equations and work? How did you approach the problem?

Comment: @JohnD ok i add my solution and explained why i'm stuck

Comment: The Laplace transform for the 100V source is incorrect.

Comment: @RussellH could you explain more

Comment: When the  switch is closed, then both the voltage source an the capacitance are applied to the circuit. Both appear as step functions. Also your KVL equation is incomplete.

Comment: @S.alhaider Are you looking for the solution for current? Voltage? Both? And you are looking for the specific solution? Or? Do you already understand how to handle initial conditions with Laplace? For this circuit, the simpler solution starts by solving for the current. (All the components are in series so they share the same currents.)

Comment: This can "oh so easily" be converted to a single voltage source initial condition. Get hold of a simulator and prove this to yourself and then solve.

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of in the ballpark. Just one or two messed up figures.

The circuit could be represented as, pretty much as you already managed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmqZ7F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The KVL would be \$\frac{50}{s}+I\cdot\frac1{s C}+I\cdot R+I\cdot s L=\frac{100}{s}\$ or \$\left(s^2+\frac{R}{L}s+\frac1{L C}\right)I=\frac{50}{L}\$. Stuffing in values gets \$\left(s^2+1.6\times 10^4s+10^8\right)I=10^4\$. Re-arrange that for \$I\$ and you are done.

If you want the voltage on the capacitor, then from knowing that \$\mathscr{L}\left\{i\right\}=C\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} v\right\}\$ generates \$I=C\left(s V-v_0\right)\$. (\$v_0=50\:\text{V}\$, of course.) So \$\left(s^2+1.6\times 10^4s+10^8\right)2\:\mu\left(s V-50\right)=10^4\$.

This results in \$s\left(s^2+1.6\times 10^4s+10^8\right)V=5\times 10^9+5\times 10^1\left(s^2+1.6\times 10^4s+10^8\right)\$. Solve that for \$V\$ and you are done.

Of course, if you want to plot in the time domain you'll need to take the inverse Laplace.

Here is what LTspice says:

[image]

Here's what the inverse Laplace (using Wolfram Alpha) says:

[image]

They match up.

Answer (score 0):

Now, when the switch is in position 'a' we can see that the voltage across the capacitor is given by:

$$\text{V}_{\text{C}\space|\space\text{a}}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\underbrace{\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)+\text{R}_1}}_{=\space\text{voltage divider}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{a}}}{\text{s}}}_{=\space\text{input voltage}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

Using the final value theorem we get:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{V}_{\text{C}\space|\space\text{a}}\left(t\right)=\lim_{\text{s}\space\to\space0}\text{s}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)+\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{a}}}{\text{s}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{a}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag2$$

Now, when the switch changes to position 'b' we have the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}\left(t\right)&=\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_{\text{R}_3}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_{\text{C}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}\left(t\right)&=\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)&=\text{I}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\\
\\
\text{V}_{\text{R}_3}\left(t\right)&=\text{I}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_3\\
\\
\text{I}\left(t\right)&=\text{V}_{\text{C}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\\
\\
\text{I}\left(0\right)&=0\\
\\
\text{V}_{\text{C}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}\left(0\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{a}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Solving this gives:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle2\sqrt{\text{C}}\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}_3t}{2\text{L}}\right)\left(\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{b}}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{a}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\right)}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{CR}_3^2-4\text{L}}}\cdot\sinh\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{CR}_3^2-4\text{L}}}{\displaystyle2\text{L}\sqrt{\text{C}}}\cdot t\right)\tag4$$

---

Using your values, we get:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\frac{5}{3} e^{-8000 t} \sin (6000 t)\tag5$$