# Inductor and Capacitor Timer - Strange behaviour: Need help understanding

Tags: capacitor, inductor, passive-networks

I am learning about coils for a boost converter project I’m working on. In my experiments I came across this strange phenomenon.

We have an ideal capacitor being charged by an ideal coil with a diode between the two.
[image: First test circuit, with a diode]

As we can see the **capacitor does charge up**, however **to a much higher voltage than the supply voltage. 8.349 V in this case.** Additionally, the charging current does not in any way resemble an RC timer circuit, instead looking at a parabola. I think the capacitor charged to a higher voltage because the coil was opposing the change in current, inducing voltage into the capacitor.

**My questions are:**

1. How do I calculate the maximum capacitor voltage in this circuit?
2. How do I calculate the maximum current flowing through the coil?
3. How do I calculate the average charge current?
4. How do I calculate the charge time *(how long it takes the capacitor
   to reach its maximum voltage (question 1) from 0V?)*

**Additionally, I would like to ask about this behavior:**

If I switch out the diode for an 2 Ω resistor, which is the combined ESR of my capacitor and coil, the simulator shows me that the circuit starts oscillating, yet **I have not been able to observe this behavior in real life**, well maybe there is something but it’s nowhere near as apparent as the simulator.
[image: Second test cicruit, with a resistor instead of the diode]
[image: Same circuit in real life]

**Is this just a fault in the simulator or is something else affecting my circuit?** I have precisely measured the values of my components when I represented them in the simulator. I have looked up terms like “LC timer” in google trying to look for an answer, but all I found were LC tank circuits, but these look very different to what I have here.

Thank you very much for all help and explanations.

Comment: Many questions. Let me just start with the first one. It's a 2nd order differential equation, plus it appears because of the diode also a non-linear product-log element added, and the specific solutions will require some calculus skill even if the diode aspect is minimized through simplifying assumption. (The second schematic is easier as a resistor is less complex than a diode. But still requires calculus skill.) Do you feel comfortable with various methods for solving ordinary differential equations? Your last setup suggests a change in the damping factor. It's not a defect in your work.

Comment: Hello, thank You for your anwser. Even if the math is narly, I'd still be happy to see the neccessary equasions. It would show me where to look for more information.

Comment: An answer I wrote which reduced to something very close to your 2nd schematic is [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/666254). An answer I wrote which exposes you to more of the actual time-domain mathematics involved (rather than Laplace alone) is [found here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/662662). An answer that directly addresses your 2nd schematic would be something that combines the two. Are these links sufficient to get you started? Or?

Comment: Well, I've added all the *gnarlies* for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll address myself to the simulator and mathematics, shortly. They match up. That won't answer your last question about what you observed when scoping out a circuit, though. But let's say that your real components worked out to \$L=470\:\mu\text{H}\$, \$R=3.3\:\Omega\$, and \$C=220\:\mu\text{F}\$. Then you should get a plot like this:

[image]

And that appears a lot closer to what you observed.

My point, before proceeding, is that with slightly different component values the nature of how things damp-out can change the appearances like this.

To you, the difference may seem extreme -- in one case "wanting to oscillate" and in another case without any oscillation tendency. But it is only a slight tweak to go from some visible oscillation (under-damped) to no oscillation (over-damped.) There's a magic number, 1, where it is critically damped. But everything less will have some oscillation to it and everything more will have little to none. It's a sharp line that separates these two regions of behavior. But nothing to get overly concerned about, yet.

Now on to the rest...

### Your problem

Out of the skies and back down to cases.

In the time domain you have from KVL:

$$\begin{align*}
5\:\text{V}-L\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} i_t-R\cdot i_t-\frac1{C}\int i_t\:\text{d}t&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
L\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} t^2} i_t+R\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} i_t+\frac1{C}i_t&= 0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} t^2} i_t+\frac{R}{L}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} i_t+\frac1{L\,C}i_t&= 0
\\\\
\left(\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} t^2}+\frac{R}{L}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} +\frac1{L\,C}\right)i_t&= 0
\\\\
\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)i_t&= 0
\end{align*}$$

*(Mathematicians are ever trying to get at the root ideas. But like all of us, also wanting to avoid scribbling a lot, which can cloud intuition. The replacement of \$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} t^2}\$ by \$D^2\$ is an obvious step, textually. But it is much more. As Gödel certainly made abundantly clear in the means by which he proved his incompleteness theorem. Just consider \$D\$ as an **operator** that **operates on** what follows it.)*

The above is what's called an ***homogeneous*** equation. (Recognized because the right hand side is zero, which makes it easier to solve.) There are also ***inhomogeneous*** equations, where the right side isn't zero and may be a nasty-looking expression of its own right. Those are harder and one of the goals would then be to try to turn it back into an homogeneous equation, somehow, before attempting a solution. You'll find such discussions in the first book I mentioned.

There's still a problem. We are not looking for \$i_t\$ but instead \$v_t\$. From the capacitor equation, \$i_t=C\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v_t\$, or more simply as \$i_t=C\left(D\: v_t\right)\$, and just substitute that into the above:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)i_t&= 0
\\\\
\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)C\left(D\: v_t\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)&= 0
\\\\
\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)\left(D\: v_t\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)&= 0
\\\\
\left(D\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right) v_t&= 0
\end{align*}$$

Note the right side is zero. You also know that \$v_t\$ is, by itself, some function that is not zero (we don't expect it to be -- and in fact that's the function we are looking to find.) So this means that the other part, namely \$\left(D\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)\$ must always somehow magically *annihilate* \$v_t\$ so that the result is always zero. Otherwise, the equation fails somewhere.

Annihilators like this have been analyzed, at length. It turns out that \$D-\alpha\$ annihilates functions of the general form of \$f\left(t\right)=A_0\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\$ and that \$\left(D-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\$ annihilates functions of the general form of \$g\left(t\right)=A_0\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\cos\left(\beta\,t\right) + A_1\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\$.

Multiplied together, \$\left(D\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)\$ and \$\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)\$, would annihilate \$v_t=f\left(t\right)+g\left(t\right)\$.

\$\left(D\vphantom{\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}}\right)\$ fits \$D-\alpha\$ if \$\alpha=0\$. Which means \$f\left(t\right)=A_0\$. That's easy.

\$\left(D^2+\frac{R}{L}D +\frac1{L\,C}\right)\$ fits \$\left(D-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\$ if, given \$a=\frac{R}{L}\$ and \$b=\frac1{L\,C}\$, then \$\alpha=-\frac12 a=-\frac12\frac{R}{L}\$ and \$\beta=\pm\frac12\sqrt{4b-a^2}=\pm\frac12\sqrt{4\frac1{L\,C}-\left(\frac{R}{L}\right)^2}\$. With your part values, find \$\alpha=-1055.27638\$ and \$\beta=\pm 2006.12986\$. (For \$\beta\$, choose only the \$+\$ version of the pedantic \$\pm\$, though.)

Which means \$g\left(t\right)=A_0\,e^{^{-1055.27638\,t}}\cos\left(2006.12986\,t\right) + A_1\,e^{^{-1055.27638\,t}}\sin\left(2006.12986\,t\right)\$

Summed find \$v_t=A_0+A_1\,e^{^{-1055.27638\,t}}\cos\left(2006.12986\,t\right) + A_2\,e^{^{-1055.27638\,t}}\sin\left(2006.12986\,t\right)\$.

At \$t=0\$, we know \$v_t=0\$ so \$A_0+A_1=0\$. At \$t=\infty\$ we know that \$v_\infty=5\:\text{V}\$. So \$A_0=5\$ and \$A_1=-5\$. We also know that \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v_t=0\$. This means that \$A_2=-5\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\$ (take the derivative of \$v_t\$, substitute in \$t=0\$, \$A_0=5\$ and \$A_1=-5\$, to find this.) Therefore, the specific solution is:

$$v_{_\text{C}}\left(t\right)=5\:\text{V}\left(1-\exp\left(\alpha t\right)\left[\cos\left(\beta t\right)-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\cdot\sin\left(\beta t\right)\right]\right)$$

Here's LTspice's curve:

[image]

Putting the equation into the [Desmos plot applet](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) available on the web I get:

[image]

I'm calling that a match. Math does work.

*Note, at the outset I suggested one of your practical circuit curves might be the result of using values somewhat different than simulated. (Recall \$L=470\:\mu\text{H}\$, \$R=3.3\:\Omega\$, and \$C=220\:\mu\text{F}\$?) Here, you'd find \$\beta\$ is imaginary (plug in the values and see.) That's because it's over-damped. In over-damped situations, reverse the sign inside the square-root function for \$\beta\$ and convert the cosine and sine functions in the solution into hyperbolic cosine and sine functions.*

*Below are both curves (the simulated one based on values you provided and the over-damped suggestion I made at the beginning using the values I provided there for illustration purposes) for comparison about how relatively small changes in part values can yield different-looking curves:*

[image]

### Laplace

In Laplace, the KVL is \$\frac{5}{s}-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot s L-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot R-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot\frac1{s C}=0\$ or \$\left(s^2+ \frac{R}{L} s+\frac1{L C}\right)I_{_\text{C}}=\frac{5}{L}\$.

The logic here is that you start by adding the voltage source (\$\frac{5}{s}\$) and then subtracting the voltages across each element. Due to KCL, this must result in zero. (The sum of the voltage differences must equal the supply voltage.)

You may pause a moment and notice the similarity of the above Laplace statement and the earlier time-domain version using things like \$D^2\$ and \$D\$ where \$s^2\$ and \$s\$ now appear here. There's good reason for that similarity. (But for a later time. Not here.)

Let's just solve for \$I_{_\text{C}}\$:

$$I_{_\text{C}}=\frac{\frac{5}{L}}{s^2+ \frac{R}{L} s+\frac1{L C}}$$

But \$V_{_\text{C}}\$ is just the current times the capacitor's impedance, so \$V_{_\text{C}}=\frac1{s C} I_{_\text{C}}\$ and therefore:

$$V_{_\text{C}}=\frac5{s}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{L\,C}}{s^2+ \frac{R}{L} s+\frac1{L C}}$$

The inverse Laplace transform of that will give the same time-domain solution already worked out. (Compare prior time-domain results above with [this link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7B995%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-6%7D%5Ccdot195.6%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-6%7D%7D%7D%7Bs%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2.1%7D%7B995%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-6%7D%7D%5Ccdot%20s%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B995%5Ccdot%2010%5E%7B-6%7D%5Ccdot%20195.6%5Ccdot%2010%5E%7B-6%7D%7D%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bs%7D?or=input).)

There's a reason why, once learned, folks often first reach for Laplace.

### Self-study

I'd like to suggest that you get a really good textbook on differential equations. One, hopefully, where there was some attempt writing to readers interested in self-study. There are two or three I like right now:

1. R. Kent Nagle & Edward B. Saff & Arthur David Snider, 9th edition, *"Fundamentals of Differential Equations"*. I really like their approach. But how well it 'sings to your mind' will be another question.

   It more of a *straight arrow* aimed right at differential equations. That said, it's a really good straight arrow and I highly recommend their textbook.
2. Gilbert Strang (anything by him is good), 5th edition, *"Differential Equations and Linear Algebra"*. Gilbert Strang really can help you with understanding linear matrices, vector spaces, and their application to solutions.

   You'll gain some *maturity* and a much higher level of view from which to work, reading his books. For example, his *"Linear Algebra and Learning from Data"* gets right down to the business of understanding columnspace, rowspace, and the two nullspaces that relate to matrix operations so that you aren't down in the weeds but instead operating at a top level perspective that provides intuitions you won't otherwise get.

   I consider Dr. Strang's writing as essential for moving from a low-level (assembly coder's) point of view and thus more towards a mature understanding of what in the heck is really going on. More, his work will motivate you towards graph theoretic approaches to circuits (where KVL resides in the columnspace, KCL resides in the rowspace, and the two Kirchhoff laws reside in the left and right nullspaces. It's a piece of beauty to behold when you get to this place in circuit theory. Dr. Strang is a practical way of getting there.

   Then, if interested in more theory, I can finally then recommend:
3. Wai-Kai Chen's *"Graph Theory and Its Engineering Applications*". The author here assumes you are mathematically mature. So don't go here until you feel more ready for that. But there is nothing quite like it for studying circuit theory from a graph-theoretic point of view. By the 2nd chapter you are off and running with circuit graphs that are practical and meaningful.

   This is a blend of both theory (mostly) and practice (enough to get points across.) But it provides very solid grounding. Do not go here, though, until you are feeling somewhat comfortable with the first half of #1 above and at least the first few chapters of #2 above. But if you are looking to seriously get down into the business end of understanding circuit theory at a profound level, I recommend this book as the segue for that. It's also a key work -- seminal. So you really cannot avoid it, if you are getting serious about this area.

Sorry about the above. But it may help, someday.